# get angular route parameters in child components

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

I'm having a very tough time properly getting a handle on route parameters for child components.

I have a route parameter like so:

```
{ path: 'bin-view/:pileid', loadChildren: () => import(`./bin-view/bin-view.module`).then(m => m.BinViewModule) }
```

and the link where I pass in the parameter:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/bin-view', _pileid]" routerLinkActive="active">view bin</a>
```

Then in my child component context I have the following:

```
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {

    private _pileid;

    constructor(private _activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) { 
        this._pileid = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('pileid');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this._pileid);
    }

}
```

But this keeps giving me a `null` value. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you see the parameter in the URL? Also, you should not use snapshot if there's a possibility that the component will be re-used. May be, the component is initialized first without the parameter and that sets the property to null, and since you are using snapshot, it will not be updated. Try this._activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe() instead. Read more here : https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action

Comment: Yes, when I click on the `[router-link]` href I'm seeing the _pileid value in the URL:
`/bin-view/517530/overview`, so it's definitely populating the URL properly. Just not able to read it when I get into a child component context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `parent` insead of `snapshot.paramMap`

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.pileid = params[pileid];
  });
}
```

Comment: Is this brittle by having a reference to `.parent`? Or is there a more robust way to reference the param?

Comment: since it is the parent's params, it make sense to reference the parent.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your help. Makes sense!